# Convert an array-like string into an array?

Tags: ruby

I am returning data from an api that is an array of arrays.

```
puts response.body 
[["20131001", 7], ["20131002", 15], ["20131003", 5]]
```

I need to break this up so I can insert it into a database table. However, this is being returned as a string.

```
results = response.body
puts results.class
String
```

If I convert it to an array it will have a count of 1.

```
results_arr =* results
puts results_arr.class
Array
puts results_arr.count
1
```

What is the best way to convert this into an array so I can access the elements?

UPDATE:

I have no idea why this was marked as off-topic. I'll provide an example of this problem. After I converted response.body into an array with the =* operator (confirmed by results_arr.class) I went to parse the array with this block which got the following results.

```
  results_arr.each do |date|
    puts date[0]
  end
```

This returned:

```
[
```

I believe that the issue is that converting the String returned in response.body to an Array correctly. I want to know the right way to do it. The answer provided the solution.

Comment: why is my question off-topic? Its a Ruby programming question. I provided an example and my attempts that did not work. Answers were provided that solved my problem. I do not understand why this was voted down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`YAML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html#module-YAML-label-Usage) libaray of Ruby

```
require 'yaml'

s = '[["20131001", 7], ["20131002", 15], ["20131003", 5]]'
YAML.load(s) # => [["20131001", 7], ["20131002", 15], ["20131003", 5]]
```

Or [`JSON#parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse)

```
require 'json'

s = '[["20131001", 7], ["20131002", 15], ["20131003", 5]]'
JSON.parse(s) # => [["20131001", 7], ["20131002", 15], ["20131003", 5]]
```

Comment: I guess it was meant as a JSON, not YAML. But it's hard to tell from one example...

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thanks for providing some guidance. I have no idea why my question was voted down. I appreciate your help.